# R: aggregate based of multiple columns

Tags: r, aggregate, subset, plyr, apply

How can I sum DBH and Basal area by Tree.Species Compartment, Stand, Transect and Plot?

```
Tree.Species    DBH  Basal Area   Compartment   Stand   Transect Plot 
Sugar Maple     16.4    211.1336    107           20        2       3
Sugar Maple     25.1    494.55785   107           20        2       3 
Hemlock         15.1    178.98785   209           30        1       2
```

I was trying:

```
aggregate(.~ Compartment + Stand + Transect + Plot + Tree.Speices, data = Trees, FUN = sum)
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(DBH, Basal.Area, Transect..,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Transect')
```

My variables unique values and there are not all possible combinations in the data.

```
Compartment: 107 209 310 231
Stand: 20 110  30 240  80 300
Transect: 1 2 3
Plot: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

dput:

```
structure(list(Tree.Speices = structure(c(53L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 
49L, 11L, 49L, 12L, 49L, 4L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 53L, 49L, 49L, 4L, 
4L, 33L, 4L, 11L, 53L, 11L, 53L, 53L, 21L, 21L, 53L, 49L, 53L, 
49L, 49L, 53L, 21L, 4L, 4L, 49L, 12L, 21L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 
9L, 49L, 49L, 11L, 11L, 53L, 47L, 33L, 11L, 5L, 49L, 11L, 11L, 
38L, 11L, 49L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 49L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 47L, 49L, 
49L, 49L, 47L, 49L, 33L, 4L, 4L, 47L, 4L, 11L, 49L, 53L, 49L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 49L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 49L, 11L, 49L, 47L, 
49L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 21L), .Label = c("American Elm", "Aspen", 
"Balsam", "Basswood", "Beech", "Big-Toothed Aspen", "Black Cherry", 
"Cedar", "Cottonwood", "Elm", "Hemlock", "Hop Hornbeam", "paper birch", 
"Paper Birch", "Poplar", "Quaking Aspen", "Red Maple", "Red Oak", 
"Red Spruce", "snag", "Snag", "Snag (Aspen)", "Snag (Basswood)", 
"Snag (Beech)", "Snag (Big-Toothed Aspen)", "SNAG (Big-Toothed Aspen)", 
"snag (conifer)", "Snag (Conifer)", "Snag (Cottonwood)", "Snag (Elm)", 
"Snag (hardwood)", "snag (Hemlock)", "Snag (Hemlock)", "SNAG (Hemlock)", 
"Snag (maple)", "Snag (Maple)", "Snag (Oak)", "Snag (Paper Birch)", 
"Snag (Poplar)", "Snag (Red Maple)", "snag (Sugar Maple)", "Snag (Sugar Maple)", 
"Snag (Sugar)", "Snag (White Ash)", "Snag (White Pine)", "snag (Yellow Birch)", 
"Snag (Yellow Birch)", "SNAG (Yellow Birch)", "Sugar Maple", 
"White Ash", "White Birch", "White Pine", "Yellow Birch"), class = "factor"), 
    DBH = c(55.7, 21.3, 14, 38, 6.5, 20.3, 33.2, 6.3, 30.5, 22.3, 
    32.7, 8.9, 41.8, 30, 24.6, 13.8, 56.6, 49.5, 49.9, 63.2, 
    28, 39, 21, 25.7, 29.9, 38, 17.5, 22.4, 6.2, 20.3, 18.3, 
    21, 24.7, 49.5, 6.4, 30.3, 19.4, 6, 37.8, 24.6, 24.4, 9.5, 
    17.4, 49.2, 26, 31, 23.6, 19.8, 37.9, 25.8, 31.5, 18.1, 34.4, 
    59.7, 28.2, 21, 16.4, 23.7, 34.4, 24.7, 15.4, 12, 24.2, 34.2, 
    19.4, 15.1, 34.9, 34.8, 6.6, 61.2, 25.4, 38.8, 28.9, 32.3, 
    43.9, 33.8, 27.1, 37, 21.2, 26.4, 27.4, 10.6, 55.1, 69.4, 
    24, 25.4, 51, 20.2, 14.3, 31.8, 48.8, 38.3, 19.6, 26.3, 34.5, 
    6.3, 41.3, 32.6, 14.6, 9.1, 57.8), Basal.Area = c(2435.45465, 
    356.14665, 153.86, 1133.54, 33.16625, 323.49065, 865.2584, 
    31.15665, 730.24625, 390.37265, 839.39265, 62.17985, 1371.5834, 
    706.5, 475.0506, 149.4954, 2514.7946, 1923.44625, 1954.65785, 
    3135.4784, 615.44, 1193.985, 346.185, 518.48465, 701.79785, 
    1133.54, 240.40625, 393.8816, 30.1754, 323.49065, 262.88865, 
    346.185, 478.92065, 1923.44625, 32.1536, 720.70065, 295.4426, 
    28.26, 1121.6394, 475.0506, 467.3576, 70.84625, 237.6666, 
    1900.2024, 530.66, 754.385, 437.2136, 307.7514, 1127.58185, 
    522.5274, 778.91625, 257.17385, 928.9376, 2797.81065, 624.2634, 
    346.185, 211.1336, 440.92665, 928.9376, 478.92065, 186.1706, 
    113.04, 459.7274, 918.1674, 295.4426, 178.98785, 956.13785, 
    950.6664, 34.1946, 2940.1704, 506.4506, 1181.7704, 655.63985, 
    818.98265, 1512.85985, 896.8154, 576.51185, 1074.665, 352.8104, 
    547.1136, 589.3466, 88.2026, 2383.26785, 3780.8426, 452.16, 
    506.4506, 2041.785, 320.3114, 160.52465, 793.8234, 1869.4304, 
    1151.50865, 301.5656, 542.97665, 934.34625, 31.15665, 1338.96665, 
    834.2666, 167.3306, 65.00585, 2622.5594), Compartment = c(107L, 
    107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
    107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
    107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
    107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
    107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
    107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
    107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
    107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
    107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 
    107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L, 107L
    ), Stand = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), Transect.. = c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Plot.. = c(1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Tree.Speices", 
"DBH", "Basal.Area", "Compartment", "Stand", "Transect..", "Plot.."
), row.names = 67:167, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How do the variables have different lengths? Is `Trees` not in a data frame? (Could you possibly share the output of `dput(Trees)`?)

Comment: First, make the names of your data valid using `make.names`: `names(Trees) <- make.names(names(Trees))`. Then, use `cbind` in order to specify multiple response variables `aggregate(cbind(DBH, Basal.Area) ~ Compartment + Stand + Transect + Plot + Tree.Species, data = Trees, FUN = sum)`

Comment: I have 2540 observations so it doesn't let me post the whole dput output. It's a dataframe, I meant that not every transect has 6 plots, it looks like that  is causing the problem, but I'm not sure.
`

Comment: I still got the error: `Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(DBH, Basal.Area) ~ Compartment +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Transect')` I've added a subset of my data to my question.

Comment: You are specifying wrong names. First take a look at `names(Tree)` and then build your calls. Anyway, `aggregate(cbind(DBH, Basal.Area) ~ Compartment + Stand + Transect.. + Plot.. + Tree.Speices, data = Trees, FUN = sum)` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two column names have two dots at the end and Species is incorrectly spelled:

```
> names(Trees)
[1] "Tree.Speices" "DBH"          "Basal.Area"   "Compartment"  "Stand"       
[6] "Transect.."   "Plot.."
```

Try:

```
aggregate(.~ Compartment + Stand + Transect.. + Plot.. + Tree.Speices, 
   data = Trees, FUN = sum)
```

or remove the dots at the end of all names and correct the spelling:

```
names(Trees) <- sub("\\.+$", "", names(Trees))
names(Trees) <- sub("Speices", "Species", names(Trees))
aggregate(.~ Compartment + Stand + Transect + Plot + Tree.Species, 
   data = Trees, FUN = sum)
```